# Why are the partial derivatives of $f(x,y)=xy/(x^4+y^4)$ equal to $0$ at $(0,0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

[image]

[image]

Read "$x=0$ or $y=0 $" as $x=0\cup y=0$

I don't understand the section of the solution highlighted in green.

For instance if: $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x\neq0$

and $f(0)=0
$

I cannot just say $f(0)=0 \implies f'(0)=0 \implies f$ is differentiable at $0$

It has to be shown via the definition of the derivative. So why in this case does the author take such a simplistic approach?

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of $x=0$ or $y=0$ is not at one point $(0,0)$.  $x=0$ means that you are restricted to the $y$ axis.  All along that axis $f(x,y)=0$.  Because they have defined $f(x,y)$ to be zero at $(0,0)$ means that the partial derivative there, along the $y$ axis, will be zero.  If $x$ is not zero then the denominator is not zero and so the derivative exists as the quotient of two polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is that for $x=0$ and *every* $y$, you have $f(x,y)=0$, i.e. for $x=0$ the induced function on $y$ is constant, thus differentiable. The same goes for $y=0$.